# In mercurial, what is .hg\store\dh directory?

Tags: mercurial

I noticed my mercurial repos has an .hg\store\dh directory. What is the purpose of that directory?

Also, I notice the directory names in that directory are only 8 characters.  That seems like an issue on an OS that allows 255 character length directory names.

Stephen

Answer (score 4):

The `dh` folder is used for the [`fncache`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/fncacheRepoFormat), to overcome the limited file name problems. Based on the documentation found [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/fncacheRepoFormat#Hashing_of_long_paths),

> All paths that are hashed are stored in the directory 'dh' inside
>   '.hg/store'. Non-hashed paths are stored inside '.hg/store/data'.
>
> The hashing used is the sha1 digest (40 characters) of the direncoded
>   path below '.hg/store', as pre-encoded by mercurial.filelog.encodedir.
>
> For the hashencoded path, the first eight characters of the first n
>   directory levels are taken (converted to lowercase), where n is
>   adapted slightly to use more levels if space allows (see
>   store.hybridencode). If space allows, the filename before the hash
>   value is filled up with to lowercase converted chars from the filename
>   of the input path.
>
> **As you can see, the path encoding done may fold multiple files
>   originating from different input path directories into the same
>   encoded path directory. The sha1 digest part of the filename ensures
>   that the filenames are distinct and no name clashes occur.**

So no, the 8 charaters is not an issue, as the ambiguities are solved by the hash method.